Regular expression to match specific words seperated by spaces
I have a list of say 5 words (foo bar foobar footable somebar). This list of words will be provided as a string each separated by space and in any order. I need a regex matching below requirements

inputted string should contain only the 5 above mentioned words
each word separated by space
each word only once
regex should match the entire string - if any portion does not match above criteria, it should be failed match

So far I have this
(\b(foo|bar|foobar|footable|somebar)\b\ *){1,5}

Matches only the mentioned words
Words separated by space

Need a solution for the 3rd & 4th requirements

each word only once
regex should match the entire string - if any portion of the string does not match above criteria, it should be a failed match


Figured the 4th requirement ^((\b(foo|bar|foobar|footable|somebar)\b\ *){1,5})$

You should make clear what you mean by a "word". Is it a string comprised of word characters, \w (letters, digits and the underscore) or just English letters or something else.

Akhill, if elsewhere you require each of the five words to be present,  your expression for the 4th requirement is unnecessary demanding: it's sufficient to require that the sentence contain exactly five words, not necessarily five particularly words. Note that the string "bar bar bar bar bar" matches your regex. You are also permitting the string to end with spaces, which you may or may not want. See @Barmar's answer.

Start with a regular expression that matches exactly 5 words:
^(?:\w+\s+){4}\w+$

The anchors ensure that this matches the entire string.
Then prefix this with lookaheads that match each of the words.
(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*\bfoobar\b)(?=.*\bfootable\b)(?=.*\bsomebar\b)^(?:\w+\s+){4}\w+$

DEMO

Perhaps ^(?:\w+ ){4}\w+$ would be better in view OP's requirement #2. As is, "a\nb\nc\n\d\ne" would match.

Their regexp has <space>*, so I presume any number of spaces are allowed between words, not exactly a single space. And it's common to interpret "space" as meaning any whitespace. But it's easy for them to make this more specific if necessary. And if the input is just a single line, the distinction is irrelevant.

Thanks @Barmar this works. I am not very familiar with lookaheads so was trying out different ways to match each word only once

Should have mentioned this in the original post but I am using extended grep which doesnt support lookaheads. Is this achievable without lookaheads?

Akhil, I believe your only recourse to construct a regular expression without lookaheads would be to formulate an alternation with 5432 = 120 parts. If, for example, three words must be present, "a", "b","c", you could write ^(?:a b c|a c b|b a c|b c a|c a b|c b a)$ (32 = 6 parts). That's of course impractical, certainly inferior to simply enforcing the requirement in code. I take it you can't use grep -P, grep with Perl-compatible regular expressions, which supports lookarounds.

Cary, yes cant use grep -P as I am on macOS. Thanks for your help, helped me read more around the topics

A subroutine or a pre-defined subroutine can be used to accomplish this task.

The regex with a subroutine:

^(foobar|footable|somebar|bar|foo)\s+(?!\1\b)((?1))\s+(?!(?:\1|\2)\b)((?1))\s+(?!(?:\1|\2|\3)\b)((?1))\s+(?!(?:\1|\2|\3|\4)\b)(?1)$

An explanation of this regex can be found here.

The regex with a pre-defined subroutine:

(?(DEFINE)(?<words>foobar|footable|somebar|bar|foo))^((?&words))\s+(?!\2\b)((?&words))\s+(?!(?:\2|\3)\b)((?&words))\s+(?!(?:\2|\3|\4)\b)((?&words))\s+(?!(?:\2|\3|\4|\5)\b)(?&words)$

An explanation of this regex is here.The demo of using this regex with grep is here.

"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."
I understand that this is probably a homework exercise but don't use a regexp for this in the real world, just write a simple little script, e.g. using any awk in any shell on every Unix box for any space-separated strings containing any non-space characters (including regexp metachars) you want to compare:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numAllowed = split(allow,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        allowed[tmp[i]]
    }

    numCheck = split(check,tmp)
    if ( numCheck != numAllowed ) {
        err = err "Error: Invalid number of words: " numCheck+0 ORS
    }

    for (i in tmp) {
        word = tmp[i]
        if ( !(word in allowed) ) {
            err = err "Error: Invalid word: " word ORS
        }
        if ( seen[word]++ ) {
            err = err "Error: Repeated word: " word ORS
        }
    }

    if ( err ) {
        printf "%s", err
        exit 1
    }
    else {
        print "Valid"
    }
}


$ awk -v allow='foo bar foobar footable somebar' -v check='foobar foo footable somebar bar' -f tst.awk
Valid


$ awk -v allow='foo bar foobar footable somebar' -v check='foo bar foo foobar stuff footable somebar' -f tst.awk
Error: Invalid number of words: 7
Error: Repeated word: foo
Error: Invalid word: stuff

